# ASUS Xonar U7 no sound

Tags: 14.04

I am with Ubunutu 14.04 with latest updates.
I connected USB ASUS Xonar U7, then connected headphones. No sound I can hear.
Below is the output of 'pacmd list-sinks'

```
pacmd list-sinks
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> 3 sink(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_05.1.hdmi-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9050
    volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0.00 dB 1: 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 100%
                 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 26.00 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_05.1>
    module: 5
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.id = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "3"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfe8e8000 irq 19"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:05.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:05.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        device.product.id = "970f"
        device.product.name = "M4A785TD Motherboard"
        device.string = "hdmi:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.description = "M4A785TD Motherboard Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "ATI RS690/780 HDMI"
        alsa.components = "HDA:1002791a,00791a00,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    active port: <hdmi-output-0>
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.usb-ASUS_USB_Audio_Device-00-Device.iec958-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9048
    volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0.00 dB 1: 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 100%
                 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 26.62 ms
    max request: 3 KiB
    max rewind: 344 KiB
    monitor source: 1
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 20.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.usb-ASUS_USB_Audio_Device-00-Device>
    module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "USB Audio Device"
        alsa.long_card_name = "ASUS USB Audio Device at usb-0000:00:12.2-1, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:12.2-usb-0:1:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/sound/card2"
        udev.id = "usb-ASUS_USB_Audio_Device-00-Device"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "1043"
        device.vendor.name = "iCreate Technologies Corp."
        device.product.id = "8586"
        device.product.name = "USB Audio Device"
        device.serial = "ASUS_USB_Audio_Device"
        device.string = "iec958:2"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "iec958-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
        device.description = "USB Audio Device Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
        alsa.components = "USB1043:8586"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    ports:
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

    active port: <iec958-stereo-output>
  * index: 2
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9959
    volume: 0:  88% 1:  88%
            0: -3.33 dB 1: -3.33 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 100%
                 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 2
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 2 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_14.2>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "VT1708S Analog"
        alsa.id = "VT1708S Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI SB"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI SB at 0xfe6f4000 irq 16"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        device.product.id = "4383"
        device.product.name = "M4A785TD Motherboard"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "VIA VT1708S"
        alsa.components = "HDA:11060397,1043836c,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output: Analog Output (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output>
```

Heres is the output of

```
lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. M4A785TD Motherboard
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
    Memory at fe6f4000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
--
01:05.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4200 Series]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. M4A785TD Motherboard
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at fe8e8000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

02:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
```

Please help me to start my Xonar U7 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the Output playback device from the icon close to the clock in the top panel of your desktop. You do not need to change any configuration!